# Можно ли остаться авторизированным на сайте, если мы его вставляем в iframe

Tags: html, cookie, iframe

Есть сайт1 и сайт2 на котором айфрейм с первого сайта, возможно ли оставаться залогиненным на первом сайте, как обстоят дела с куками? Разъясните

Comment: Почему нет? Разные домены, разные куки, друг о друге ничего не знают, затереть не могут. Правда многое зависит от политик браузеров  - фреймы часто сильно задушены ограничениями ради безопасности.